# CString object always return pointer value

Tags: c++, mfc

In visual studio 2015 environment, I just made simple Win32 console application program project to study MFC. (Also, I check on adding common header file of MFC in project Wizard process)

And Here is main part of this project..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Practice02.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

    if (hModule != nullptr)
    {
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, nullptr, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            wprintf(L"error: sample\n");
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            CString temp(L"Hello");
            cout << temp << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failure\n");
        nRetCode = 1;
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

My intention is to make simple program which prints CString object containing "hello" value on cmd screen.

However, after start this project, I only see the address value of this object. 
(EX. 0039841 or 003913E1 etc...)

Where should I modify this code to print real value of CString object?

Comment: Your CStrings are wide as you're compiling with `_UNICODE` defined, print to `wcout` instead.

Comment: Yes, this project use UNICODE setting. And, I change a code from "cout << temp << endl;" to "wcout << temp << endl;". However, outcome still is address value. ;(

Comment: I can't make any sense of that. For a console program, you can create a console project. Add `#include <atlstr.h>` and `#include "windows.h"` then you can use `CString` and WinAPI functions. You won't be able to use other MFC functions. Remove `CWinApp theApp;`, remove `AfxWinInit` ...

Comment: Just to explain what is going on: `std::ostream` has an overload for several pointer types. By default, it uses the `void const*` overload which then prints the hex-formatted address. Now, try to find out to which type your `CString` converts, e.g. by stepping through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following :

```
std::wcout << temp.GetString();
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for !! Thank you, :) But, can I ask you how this change make object to refer real value?

Comment: @구마왕 Internally CString has either char* or wchar*. GetString returns const wchar_t* and that works with wcout.